# (Drupal 6.28) Blocks list suddenly doesn't show correctly

Tags: 6, blocks

I realized today that blocks list (admin/build/block page) doesn't correctly show  all the blocks implemented in the site.
Most of the blocks are set as disabled and others are set in the wrong region, while fortunately the site displays every block still perfectly.
I have a custom theme (Zen subtheme).
The only "strange" thing I did recently was the installation of a new module which involved the assignment of a new block to a region.
Is there any way to restore the correct blocks list?
Maybe if I don't make any change to blocks system (and save the new configuration), my site will always display correctly, but I would prefer to have the correct blocks list restored.
Yes, I could draw a manual scheme of all blocks in the site (pages, views, etc.) and use it in case of disasters, but if I could restore it with a module it would surely be better
Thanks

Comment: So `/admin/build/block` doesn't show correctly after enabling a new module. What happens if you disable and uninstall that module?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I uninstalled that module, but nothing changed in the displaying of blocks list.
Despite the incorrect displaying, I wonder: if all the blocks are still working in the site, is there some place where the actual blocks are stored with correct regions and correct settings?

Answer (score 0):

That to me looks like an issue with theme update. Did you changed your theme recently. It yes, then try clearing your cache.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I also have read this issue can occur on updating a theme, but I did not update the theme.
All blocks are working. They are just not correctly listed.
This can be fine until I have to save the block system configuration again for a future block change.